# What is the difference between the various methods of suspending in 14.04?

Tags: power-management

Are the following  ways of suspending 14.04 the same?

- Choose menu for suspend
- close the laptop lid cover
- run `pm-suspend`.

What are their differences? Any suggestions on when to use which?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your settings. If in "Power Management" is set to suspend, when you close the lid, then it is same. But settings may differ. You can choose i.e. to hibernate, when close the lid, etc.

By default it is same.

You can try `pm-hibernate`, ot `pm-suspend-hybrid` too. They are different.

And also suspend menu item can be linked to "hybrid". But this does not work well on all systems.

Comment: Thanks. Any difference between choosing menu's suspend and running pm-suspend?

Comment: This menu item runs this command. So no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 uses `upstart` so yes suspend in all the cases you mentioned will trigger `pm-suspend`. However, with `systemd` which is the default in 15.04, `pm-suspend` is not used but instead you can use `systemd`'s own suspend/resume services (to trigger specific actions).